# Changing the master pages' background image?

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

In our asp.net project, we have a group of forms that have a solid color background and another that needs a background image.  We have an if statement on our masterpage that tells us what forms we are on:

```
 If Request.RawUrl.ToLower.Contains("shoes") Then
        lblSection.Text = "Shoe Store"
    ElseIf Request.RawUrl.ToLower.Contains("pants") Then
        lblSection.Text = "Pant Store"
    End If
```

How can I change the background image when im in the pants section?  Or should I aproach this in a different way?

Comment: Are the forms in the master page?

Comment: Yes all forms have the same master page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to turn the `<body>` tag into a server controlled tag.

e.g.

```
<body id="myBody" runat="server">
```

Then in your masterpage code, you could add a `class` to this depending on the page.

```
If Request.RawUrl.ToLower.Contains("shoes") Then
    lblSection.Text = "Shoe Store"
    myBody.Attributes.Add("class", "shoes")
ElseIf Request.RawUrl.ToLower.Contains("pants") Then
    lblSection.Text = "Pant Store"
    myBody.Attributes.Add("class", "pants")
End If
```

Then in your css you can have different backgrounds depending on the class name

```
.shoes{ background: Red; }
.pants{ background: url (imageurl); }
```

Comment: Am I changing the body tag to a server controlled tag on the master page?

Comment: Yes, do what I have done in my answer. Add the `id` and `runat="server"` part